# Not able to verify the text value using getText() and getAttribute() in protractor

Tags: javascript, jasmine, protractor

When I am using below code, it supposed to get the numeric value from webpage, however I am getting the value as `[object][object]`

Below is the code which I am using.

```
var resultText = element(by.id('output')).getAttribute();
console.log("Result text:  " + resultText);
```

I also tried with below way, however I am not able to get the correct value from webpage.

```
element(by.id('output')).each(function (element) {              
    var resultText = element.getAttribute('value').then(function(attr){
        expect(typeof attr).toBe("string");
    });
});
```

Can you please help me to get the value of element. Thanks for your help on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getAttribute()` and `getText()` always returns a promise. So you should be using the promise that it returns to get the value of the element and then console log it or use it in your expect statements. Here's how to do it -

```
element(by.id('output')).getAttribute('value').then(function(resultText){
    console.log(resultText);
    expect(typeof resultText).toBe("string");
});
```

If there are more elements with the id `output` then use `.each()` method to retrieve the value of each element.

```
element.all(by.id('output')).each(function (ele) {
    ele.getAttribute('value').then(function(attr){
        expect(typeof attr).toBe("string");
        console.log(attr); //print the value of returned by getAttribute
    });
});
```

`getText()` also works in the similar way. Here's an example -

```
element(by.id('output')).getText().then(function(text){
    console.log(text); //print the text that output element holds
});
```

More info on [getAttribute()](https://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.WebElement.prototype.getAttribute) and [getText()](https://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.WebElement.prototype.getText). Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for reply. However I am facing below issue:

Comment: What issue are you facing @Durgesh ?

Comment: Note that `each()` should be called on a result of `element.all()`. In your second example, it should be `element.all(by.id('output')).each(function (ele) { ...`.

Comment: Sorry missed that. below was the issue:                                          TypeError: undefined is not a function.    Can you please help you on this.

Comment: @Durgesh can you please post complete error and on which line or function are you getting this error? It would help if you can create a gist of your code too.

Comment: The value attribute of an input is ALWAYS a string, so your test is a bit pointless. For inputs you check the value with getAttribute (like you did) and for other elements you use getText. Also, Protractor tries to resolve those promises before falling through so you should be able to put them right into the expect.

Comment: Right, I just gave an example on how @Durgesh can get the values of getAttribute and getText as per his question.

Comment: Thanks All for your help. With this solution I am able to get the expected results. Thanks! Durgesh

Answer (score 1):

You should not explicitly wait for promises to resolve (for readability), unless you really have to. The following are valid expectations:

```
expect(element(by.id('output')).getAttribute('id')).toBe('output'); // true
```

or event shorter:

```
expect($('output').getAttribute('id')).toBe('output'); // true
```